# run jquery function on page load

Tags: jquery

Please could someone help with amending to following so that is triggered on page load rather than when a button is clicked.

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href="#search"]').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#search').addClass('open');
        $('#search > form > input[type="search"]').focus();
    });

    $('#search, #search button.close').on('click keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.target == this || event.target.className == 'close' || event.keyCode == 27) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the first event handler, as the second one relies on an event happening so I'm not sure how you expect to make that happen on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the code out of the `click` event :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#search').addClass('open');
    $('#search > form > input[type="search"]').focus();

    $('#search, #search button.close').on('click keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.target == this || event.target.className == 'close' || event.keyCode == 27) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Heru-Luin - much appreciated